# How do I replace a drive on my NAS?

Tags: raid, hardware, network-attached-storage

I have a Thecus N8800+ NAS. It has 8 2TB drives and is RAID 6. One of the drives recently has been reported as having bad blocks, though the RAID is still reported as healthy.

I want to replace the drive before it fails, but I have never administered a NAS before. How do I replace the drive and maintain data integrity? Can I just pull out the drive and replace it while things are running or do I need to shut it down somehow? How will the RAID rebuild after I replace the drive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So long as you have the right new drive and know which disk has died then you do literally just swap it out, I'd keep the UI tool up before during and after to keep an eye on the process.

Answer (score 9):

On page 117 of the manual it lists the process [here](http://www.originstorage.com/Downloads/Thecus/Manuals/N8800_UM_V2.3_EN.pdf). 
It appears you can just pull out the drives hot and it will auto-rebuild the RAID.

> Replacing Damaged Hard Drives 
>   If you are using RAID 1, RAID 5, or RAID 6 you can easily replace a damaged hard 
>   drive in the Thecus N8800 while keeping your data secure with the system’s 
>   automatic data recovery.
>   Hard Drive Damage 
>   When a hard drive is damaged and data in the RAID volume, the system LCD will 
>   display warning message also the system beeps. 
>   Replacing a Hard Drive
>    RAID Auto-Rebuild 
>   When using RAID 1, 5, 6, or 10 on the N8800, you can use the auto-rebuild function 
>   when an error is detected.
>   4. The system automatically recognizes the new hard disk and starts the 
>   auto-rebuild sequence to resume its status before the hard disk crash.

Comment: I have to go with the comment on reading the manual here - "RTFM" is *normally* an answer we avoid here, but when it comes to replacing disks in a RAID it is a very good idea to do so to make sure you know how your particular device's RAID controller will behave.